# How I can use where() for same fields?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

When I try to get records with same `created_at` and `updated_at` like:

```
->where('created_at','=','updated_at')
```

where `created_at` and `updated_at` are the same. I get nothing. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: @L.Kelmendi Model and controller shouldn't be necessary here, and it makes plenty of sense - the resulting query will give you a list of records that haven't been updated since their creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

> **whereColumn**
>
> The **whereColumn** method may be used to verify that two columns are equal

In your example it will be:

```
->whereColumn('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

Comment: I didn't know this existed. Neat!

Comment: whereColumn,  very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I think you're getting stuck on is how you're running your query. It looks like you're trying to pass in `updated_at`, but that literally means nothing to the database.

If you're wanting to get a list of all the records in a table and only display records that have EXACTLY the same `created_at` and `updated_at` columns, I would query all the records, then go through them and check. Based on how your question is phrased you don't have a hard date to check against, each date depends on the corresponding date in the same record.

Here's an example of how I would do what (I think) you want:

```
$users = User::all();

$modifiedUsers = $users->reject(function ($value, $key) {
    return !$value->created_at->isSameDay($value->updated_at);
});

dd($modifiedUsers);
```

In the above example we're getting all of the users, then we're creating a new collection with only the users that were created at and modified on the same day. Any user with two different day values for `created_at` and `updated_at` are rejected from our new collection (`$modifiedUsers`).

The way the `reject()` method works is it passes each item of the collection through to a callback and evaluates it. If the condition is `true` it rejects it from the collection. So, since we know that Laravel casts `created_at` and `updated_at` to an instance of Carbon, we can use Carbon's `isSameDay()` method to compare the dates. Then we simply prepend a `!` to flip the condition so we reject records that do NOT have the same created/updated dates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution will break down very quickly with lots of users. Handling this at the database level is a much better call.

Comment: It will break down for large applications, but for most it is fine. I was unaware of Laravel's ``whereColumn()`` method, so yes, that is the better way. This is merely one way of handling the problem.

Comment: WIthout `whereColumn`, the best approach would have been something like `->where('created_at','=',DB::raw('updated_at'))`.